# Qt5 - QML - AirLink RV50 - JavaScript : How to automatically trigger combobox & button on a third party router

Tags: javascript, html, qt, qml, qt5

I am using a third party router `AirLink RV50` to log-in inside a small robot I built. This robot will turn on using a relay which is triggered by a `combobox` and a related `button` which will apply the `combobox` choice. This process happens inside the user interface of the `AirLink RV50` router.

The goal of the application after I launch it:

1) log-in inside the router,

2) automatically trigger the combobox and

3) automatically apply the combobox choice using the `Apply` button.

Below the `combobox`:

[image: combobox]

below also the `Apply` Button:

[image: lay-out]

**The problem**: In order to access to the router there is an external interface that I didn't write because is from the router. I navigated through the interface and arrived to the `Apply` button and the `combobox` as shown in the `HTML` code:

So the operations are the following:

**1)** I trigger the relays using the combobox

**2)** using the mouse I have to hover on the `Apply` button

**3)** After the mouse is on the button (button hovered) I can click and apply the choice

**What is not working:** I can trigger the combobox, but I am not able to automatically hover and click on the apply button. 
**Most importantly** I noticed that the `combobx` has two major functions:

a) `onblur=onBE(this);`

b) `onfocus=setPrevVal(this)`

I believe that, in my limited knowledge of `JavaScript`, in order for the `Button` to "feel" and accept this change those functions of the `combobox` needs to be triggered.

I navigated in the debugger console of the interface and succeeded to get the two functions that are responsible to feel this change. I grabbed them and posted below.
So the solution to my problem would be to "force" this click by triggering these two functions:

```
function onBE(a) {
  var b = $(a);
  if (b.val() != gsPreviousValue || b.is(':checkbox')) {
    if ('25301' === b.attr('name') || '25501' === b.attr('name')) b = $('[name="22001-d1"]'),
    b.prop('disabled', !0),
    b.removeClass('fbtn');
    if ('checkbox' == a.type && - 1 == a.name.indexOf('2160') && - 1 == a.name.indexOf('2050') && - 1 == a.name.indexOf('55053') && - 1 == a.name.indexOf('55056')) {
      if ('0' == gV(a)) selAll(a, !0);
       else {
        var c = gEBN(a.name);
        isIE ? c[1].checked = !1 : c[0].checked = !1
      }
      c = gcbd(a);
      highlightChange(a, c);
      gTT(a) != c ? wvtt(a.name, c, !0)  : wvtt(a.name, c, !1)
    } else {
      b = $(a).parent() [0].id;
      if ('' != b) {
        for (inobjcnt = 0; inobjcnt < a.length; inobjcnt++) a[inobjcnt].selected && (b = b + '-' + a[inobjcnt].value);
        showhidetables(b)
      }
      b = getParent(a, 'TABLE');
      if (b.id == a.name.split('-') [0] || b.id == a.name.split('-') [0].replace('bin', '') || - 1 != b.title.indexOf('-')) {
        var d = '',
        e = [
        ],
        f = gEBTN(b, 'TR');
        $(b).find('tr');
        for (irowcnt = 2; irowcnt < f.length - 1; irowcnt++) {
          var g = $(f[irowcnt]).find('td');
          if ('21601' <= b.id && '21605' >= b.id || '55053' == b.id || '55056' == b.id) {
            for (var j = [
            ], h = 0; h < g.length; h++) g[h].childNodes[0].checked && j.push(gV(g[h].childNodes[0]));
            0 < j.length && (d += j.join(',') + ',')
          } else if ('20501' <= b.id && '20505' >= b.id) {
            for (h = 0; h < g.length; h++) g[h].childNodes[0].checked ? e.push(1)  : e.push(0);
            0 < e.length && (d = BintoDec(e.join('')))
          } else if (!1 == bhelix || '9061' == b.id || '9010' == b.id || '8010002' == b.id) {
            h = getcurtbl().id.replace('TB_', 'TL_G_');
            h = $(parseID(h)).val().split('|');
            for (j = 0; j < h.length; j++) if ( - 1 != h[j].indexOf('tlid=' + b.id + '&')) {
              c = h[j].split('&') [4].replace('defaultval=', '').split('-');
              break
            }
            if ('t0' != g[0].className) for (h = 0; h < g.length; h++) j = gV(g[h].childNodes[0]),
            1 < g[h].children.length && (j = gV(g[h].childNodes[1])),
            '' != j && (c[h] = j);
             else for (h = 1; h < g.length; h++) '' != encodeSpecialChars(gV(g[h].childNodes[0])) && (c[h - 1] = encodeSpecialChars(gV(g[h].childNodes[0])));
            d += c.join(cdlm) + (irowcnt == f.length - 2 ? '' : rdlm)
          } else {
            if ('t0' != g[0].className) for (h = 0; h < g.length; h++) j = gV(g[h].childNodes[0]),
            1 < g[h].children.length && (j = gV(g[h].childNodes[1])),
            d = d + (0 == h ? '' : cdlm) + j;
             else for (h = 1; h < g.length; h++) d = d + (1 == h ? '' : cdlm) + encodeSpecialChars(gV(g[h].childNodes[0]));
            d += irowcnt == f.length - 2 ? '' : rdlm
          }
        }
        b.title == d ? setTLvalue(b.id, d, !1)  : setTLvalue(b.id, d, !0);
        highlightChange(a, gV(a))
      } else highlightChange(a, gV(a)),
      wtta(a)
    }
  }
}
```

and below the second function:

```
function createselect(a, b, c, d) {
b = b.split(ssep);
var e = $('<select/>');
'' !== !c && e.attr('name', c);
e.attr({
onblur: 'onBE(this);',
onfocus: 'setPrevVal(this);'
});
'' != b[1] && e.attr('onchange', 'showHideTablesOnChange(this);');
for (c = 2; c < b.length; c++) {
var f = b[c];
if (null != f) {
var f = RegExp(f),
g = $('<option/>');
if ('' == b[c] || !1 == f.test(_global.deviceID.toUpperCase()) && !1 == f.test(enumFlag) && !1 == f.test(enumWiFlag)) {
c++;
var f = b[c],
j = f.indexOf('-'),
h = f.substr(j + 1);
g.val(f.substr(0, j));
g.html(h);
e.append(g)
} else c++
}
}
'hidden' ==
d && e.css('visibility', 'hidden');
$(a).append($(e));
'hidden' == d && $('<label/>').html('').insertBefore(e)
}
function setPrevVal(a) {
gsPreviousValue = $(a).val()
}
function configInput(a, b, c, d, e) {
'button' != d && 'cfgchk' != d && a.attr('onblur', 'onBE(this);');
'cfgchk' == d && (d = 'checkbox', a.attr('class', 'non'));
a.attr({
name: c,
type: d,
onfocus: 'setPrevVal(this);'
});
null != b && a.val(b);
e && a.attr('onclick', 'selAll(this, true);');
return a
}
function sAIC(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
'button' != e && 'cfgchk' != e && (e == scbx && isIE ? a.onblur = function () {
onBE(a)
}
 : sAtt(a, 'onblur', 'onBE(this);'));
'cfgchk' == e && (e = scbx, sCLN(a, 'non'));
sAtt(a, 'name', c);
sAtt(a, 'type', e);
null != b && sV(a, b);
f && sAtt(a, 'onclick', 'selAll(this,true);')
}
```

also below if needed the `ApplyChange()` function in `JavaScript` too:

```
function applyChange(a) {
_global.applyChangeClicked = !0;
a = void 0 == a ? !0 : !1;
var b = !1,
c = getcurtbl(),
d = $('#' + sCAT + ''),
e = $('#' + sTLCAT + '');
if ('' == d.val() && '' == e.val()) return !1;
d = gV(docEId(sCAT)).replace('&', '');
if ( - 1 != c.id.indexOf('TB_1024_Events Reporting_Events_Event ') && !chkLoad.checked && (e = c.id.replace('TB_1024_Events Reporting_Events_Event ', ''), e = parseInt(e.substring(0, 1)), !validateName('Event', 20900 + e))) return !1;
if ( - 1 != c.id.indexOf('TB_1024_I/O_Configuration_') && !chkLoad.checked) {
for (e = 2; 6 >= e; e++) for (var f = 2; 4 >= f; f++) {
var g = $('input[name="821-' + e + '-' + f + '"]');
if (0 !== g.length) {
var j = g.val(),
j = encodeSpecialChars(j);
g.val(j);
onBE(g[0])
}
}
for (e = 2; 6 >= e; e++) for (f = 2; 4 >= f; f++) g = $('input[name="821-' + e + '-' + f + '"]'),
0 !== g.length && (j = g.val(), j = decodeSpecialChars(j), g.val(j))
}
if ( - 1 != c.id.indexOf('TB_1024_Events Reporting_Actions_Action ') && !chkLoad.checked) {
if ( - 1 != d.indexOf('25301') || - 1 != d.indexOf('25501')) {
var h = $('[name="22001-d1"]'),
m = $('<img/>');
m.attr('src', 'images/loader.gif');
m.addClass('loaderimg');
h.after(m);
setTimeout(function () {
h.addClass('fbtn');
h.prop('disabled', !1);
m.remove()
}, 20000)
}
c = c.id.replace('TB_1024_Events Reporting_Actions_Action ', '');
c = parseInt(c.substring(0, 1));
if (!validateName('Action', 21900 + c)) return !1
}
if ('' != d) {
d += '&';
c = d.split('&');
e = 0;
for (f = ''; e < c.length; ) {
f = '';
for (b = 0; b <= _constant.MAX_AMT_TO_SEND && !(e >= c.length); b++, e++) 0 < c[e].length && (f += c[e] + '&');
b = GenReq('Embedded_Ace_Set_Task', f, !0, '', '', 'Changes')
}
a && (b ? alert(_message.APPLY_SUCCESSFUL)  : alert(_message.APPLY_FAILED));
if (_global.deviceID ===
_constant.MP70_WIFI || _global.deviceID === _constant.GX450_WIFI) b = d.match(/^5560\d{1}/g),
null != b && updateWifiSideMenu(b);
chkLoad.checked || ( - 1 != d.indexOf('2090') && getEventList(), - 1 != d.indexOf('2190') && getReportList())
}
b = gV(docEId(sTLCAT));
$(parseID(sTLCAT)).val();
b = b.split('|');
if (0 < b.length) for (c = 0; c < b.length; c++) if (e = b[c], '' != e) if (f = e.split('&'), g = e.split('&').slice(0, 5), j = '', '1857' == f[0].split('=') [1]) {
f[5].split('=');
var l = f[6].replace('data=', '').split(' ');
if (10 < l.length) {
for (var n = 0; n < l.length; n++) '' !=
l[n] && (j += l[n] + ' '),
0 == (n + 1) % 10 && (j = j.slice(0, - 1), f[0] = 'tlid=' + (1857 + (n - 9)), f[2] = 'incby=1', f[3] = 'colsid=' + (1857 + (n - 9)), f[5] = 'datarowcnt=10', f[6] = 'data=' + j, e = f.join('&'), GenReq('Embedded_Ace_TLSet_Task', e, !1, a && n == l.length - 1 ? _message.APPLY_SUCCESSFUL : '', _message.APPLY_FAILED, 'Changes'), j = '');
GenReq('Embedded_Ace_TLGet_Task', g.join('&'), !0, '', _message.DATA_FAILED, 'Get')
} else GenReq('Embedded_Ace_TLSet_Task', e, !1, a && '' == d && c == b.length - 1 ? _message.APPLY_SUCCESSFUL : '', _message.APPLY_FAILED, 'Changes')
} else GenReq('Embedded_Ace_TLSet_Task', e, !1, a && '' == d && c == b.length - 1 ? _message.APPLY_SUCCESSFUL : '', _message.APPLY_FAILED, 'Changes');
chkLoad.checked && (applyCancel(!1), sV(docEId(sCAT), ''), showNOTSET = chkLoad.checked = !1, getEventList(), getReportList(), docEId(sbAY).disabled = !1, docEId(sbRf).disabled = !1, _global.templateInProgress = !1, chkLoad.click());
setTimeout(Refreshtab(), 0);
$('#curAppCT').val('')
}
```

**The code**

The actual code I am using so far is the following below simple code which will do the job, but unfortunately I can't say the same for the `JavaScript` functions above, which are for me complicated to understand:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtWebEngine 1.8

ApplicationWindow{
    id: root
     width: 1640
     height: 880
     visible: true
     property string username: "user"
     property string password: "xxxxxxx"
     property string tabs: "#"
    QtObject{
        id: internals
        property string login_script: "
                var input_username = document.getElementById('username');
                input_username.value = '%1';
                var input_password = document.getElementById('password');
                input_password.value = '%2';
                LSubmit();
            ".arg(username).arg(password);

        property string get_tabs: "
                    var obtain_tabClick = document.getElementById('I/OM1');
                    obtain_tabClick.value = '%1';
                    M1C('SM1_I/O','CT_1024_I/O_Current State_!TD_1024_I/O_Current State_','I/OM1!SM1_I/O_Current StateM1','1');
                ".arg(tabs);

        property string get_relay_comboBox: "
              var comboBox = document.getElementsByName('859-2-2')[0];
              if (comboBox) {
                // Add event listener for combobx
                comboBox.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
                  console.log('Change event detected:', e);
                });
                // Get new option index by flipping the current selected index
                var newIdx = (comboBox.selectedIndex + 1) % 2;
                console.log(comboBox, comboBox.selectedIndex, newIdx);  // debug
                // set the new index
                comboBox.selectedIndex = newIdx;
                // fire change event
                comboBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
              }
              else {
                console.error('comboBox not found!');
              }
            ";
// This is one solution but did not work
//        var applyBtn = document.getElementById('btn_Apply');
//        applyBtn.value = '%1';
//        applyChange();


// This is a second solution but didn't work 
//        property string applyBtn: "
//            console.log('start')
//            var btnApply = document.getElementById('btn_Apply');
//            console.log('btnApply')
////            function fun('btnb btnhov') {
////              document.getElementById('btn_Apply').click();
////            }
//            if(btnApply) {
//                // Try add event listener for buttons
//                btnApply.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
//                    console.log('Change event detected:', e);
//                });
//              // Push button
//              // Here the button should be pushed (or hovered first????)
//            }
//            else {
//                console.error('btnApply not found!');
//            }
//        ";
    }

        Timer {
            id: timer
            interval: 5000; repeat: false
            onTriggered: view.runJavaScript(internals.login_script)
        }
        Timer {
            id: timer2
            interval: 20000; repeat: false
            onTriggered: view.runJavaScript(internals.get_tabs)
        }
        Timer {
            id: timer3
            interval: 30000; repeat: false
            onTriggered: view.runJavaScript(internals.get_relay_comboBox)
           }
//        Timer {
//            id: timer4
//            interval: 30000; repeat: false
//            onTriggered: view.runJavaScript(internals.applyBtn)
//        }

        WebEngineView {
            id: view
            anchors.fill: parent
            onUrlChanged: {
                console.log(url)
                if(url == Qt.resolvedUrl("https://166.xxx.xx.x:xxxx/")){
                    timer.running = true
                    timer2.running = true
                    timer3.running = true
//                    timer4.running = true
                }
            }
            onCertificateError: function(error) {
                error.ignoreCertificateError();
            }
            Component.onCompleted: view.url = "https://166.xxx.xx.x:xxxx"
        }
    }
```

**What I tried so far** was researching for a very long time how to by-pass those functions and force the click to the apply button. Unfortunately everything I tried was unsuccessful.

I even tried to access via `ssh` or `telnet` to check if I was able to by-pass the commands and using the `AT` command proprietary of the router. But also accessing with that was unsuccessful.
I figured that using thre `AT` commands would have been so much easier in terms also of writing a small `JavaScript` function that does the job. So far my major problem is that I am not able to understand the `JavaScript` function that fully triggers the `combobox` and, therefore, easily simulating the click.

The last thing left to try is a complete reset of the router but wanted to leave it as last option.

Thanks to anyone who could provide some guidance on this issue. I am running out of ideas, let me know if there is a simpler way or another way to move forward.

Comment: What is the operating system you are running your code? Maybe you can use AutoHotKey software.

Comment: @SoheilArmin, thank you very much for reading the question. I am using `Ubuntu 19.04`

Comment: Currently as axplained, the main problem is that I am not able to find an easy way to trigger the two `JavaScript` functions the `combobx` and the `Button` are using.

Comment: so, open your browser (chrome). open the Ctrl-Shift-I to open developer tools. in the network tab, see what is the network request for ```Embedded_Ace_TLSet_Task``` send to the backend. You can get rid of this dirty hack by taking this path.

Comment: Ok I am checking

Comment: Ok I am [here](https://i.imgur.com/seoUuOR.png) what should I do?

Comment: I clicked also [here](https://i.imgur.com/1AoGqeq.png) is this of any help for you?

Comment: well, right click on it, copy the entire curl request and upload it to your question

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much @SoheilArmin, it works finally! I wish I had written this question one week ago! If you could write the solution posted on the comment officially I can accept it so that other user don't have to struggle as I did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, for this type of hacks, it could be the last solution to tackle the problem on the GUI side.

The most proper way was to ask the original manufacturer/ developer to provide the API docs to control the target device through other methods.

Now that I assume it's not an option, you can investigate the network requests/replies that are happening after submitting your command.
Hopefully, This will give an understanding of what's happening behind the hood of the GUI<->backend communication.

As shown in pictures sent via comments, and the original code, those two js functions are simply creating a `Embedded_Ace_TLSet_Task` request to be sent to the device's internal HTTP server.

By investigating those HTTP requests, you can mimic the same behavior using [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) or even using XMLHttpRequest from within QML code without having to write C++ code.

**EDIT:**
AirLink RV50 supports RAP (Remote Access Protocol). Contact the sales representative of the company for information on how to obtain a copy of the RAP Protocol Guide.